# show that N(G) is a lattice?

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

if $G$ is a group

let N(G) be the set of normal subgroups of $G$ define $\wedge$ and $\vee$ on$ N(G)$
by $N_{1}\wedge N_{2}=N_{1}\cap N_{2}$
and $N_{1}\vee N_{2}=N_{1} N_{2}=\{n_{1}n_{2}:n_{1}\in N_{1} , n_{2}\in N_{2}\}$

show that N(G) is a lattice?
answer:

commutative laws and associative laws is hold but for idempotent laws and absorption how to continue?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Idempotency for $\cap$ is obvious, and for the join $\vee$ just use the fact that you are working with subgroups (closed under product).

The absorption laws will follow from the fact that both subgroups contain the group identity.

Comment: FOR ABsorption laws $N_{1}\wedge (N_{1}N_{2})=N_{1}\cap(N_{1}N_{2})$ and how to continue?

Comment: @zahra1234 Since the identity $e$ is in $N_2$, $N_1\subseteqN_1N_2$.